# How do I display the name of my audio card driver from the command line in Lubuntu 11.10?

Tags: linux, command-line, drivers, audio, hardware

I am running Lubuntu 11.10 and I want to display my audio / sound card driver from the command line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To find out what sound drivers are loaded, look for drivers containing `snd` and their dependencies (assuming your sound driver is part of the [ALSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) framework; most are):

```
/sbin/lsmod | grep snd
```

For example, my PC has an Intel sound chip, and amongst the dependencies of the `snd` module is the `snd_hda_intel` module, which is my chip's driver.

You can also [ask the ALSA tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29065/how-do-i-display-the-name-of-my-audio-card-driver-from-the-command-line-in-lubun/29070#29070). And to see the chip identification (independently of any driver), use `lspci` (or `lsusb`, if it's an external sound device over USB).

Answer (score 23):

ALSA's [`aplay`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/aplay) can list devices; a card may contain several devices, though:

```
$ aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD198x Analog [AD198x Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: AD198x Digital [AD198x Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `lspci -v`. For example:

```
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
        [...]
        Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
```

Comment: I have a ALC668 "Analog", it shows up as `snd_hda_codec_realtek` when doing `/sbin/lsmod | grep snd`, and there's no corresponding entry in `lspci`. How the chip connects to the chipset *without* using PCI is unknown to me. So somehow `lspci` check is not really reliable.